# i want to add image upload feature in magento custom option

Tags: magento

i want to add image upload feature in magento custom option
  i follow this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33452/add-custom-image-field-for-custom-options-in-magento 
but image not dave in database

i m trying this

```
/**
 * This observer is fired after a product is prepared saving an is used to store file uploads of custom options.



* @param $observer
 */
public function catalogProductPrepareSave($observer)
{
    if(!isset($_FILES['product']) || !isset($_FILES['product']['name']) || !isset($_FILES['product']['name']['options']))
    {
        // No files are uploaded, return ...
        return;
    }
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'options';
$io->open(array('path' => $dir));

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
$product = $observer->getProduct();

// Iterate through all file uploads:
foreach($_FILES['product']['name']['options'] as $optionId => $values)
{
    // Check for files:
    foreach($values['values'] as $valueId => $arr)
    {
        // Check for error code '0' (which is a successful file upload)
        if($_FILES['product']['error']['options'][$optionId]['values'][$valueId]['image'] == 0)
        {
            // Successful file upload:
            $newFileName = $arr['image'];
            $tmpFileName = $_FILES['product']['tmp_name']['options'][$optionId]['values'][$valueId]['image'];

            // Move uploaded file:
            $io->mv($tmpFileName, $dir . DS . $newFileName);

            // Store product option value of this product:
            $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
            $value = $option->getValueById($valueId);
            $value->setImage($newFileName);
            $value->save();
        }
    }
}

$io->close();
```

}

please help

Comment: where you are checking image not save in database. upload image and add to cart and place an order, you can see the image in order view page in backend

Comment: i m checking in database

Comment: want to add image upload option in custom option of magento

Comment: i saw you posted an answer in that link, please post question there, so you can get answer.